# Return/Pass new array to function (Swift 5)

Tags: arrays, swift

In e.g. Java you can do something like this:

```
myFunction(new MyClass[]{myclass1, myclass2, myclass3})
```

Is there an equivalent in Swift?

I tried

```
myFunction([MyClass](myclass1,myclass2,myclass3))
```

and Xcode suggested to change it to

```
myFunction([MyClass](arrayLiteral: myclass1,myclass2,myclass3))
```

but the documentary ([click](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice/1541070-init)) tells you not to call "arrayLiteral" directly.

**Edit:** The reason why I want to do this is a bit complicated:

I've got a class `MyClass` and created a bunch of instances that carry data: myclass1, myclass2, myclass3

```
init(name na:String, number nu:Int, content c:String) {....}
```

These instances I want to add to an array, which I'm then using to create an instance of a second class `MyOtherClass`:

```
init(name n:String, someotherinfo s:String, myclassarray m:[MyClass]) {....}
```

Creating the instance:

```
var myotherclassthing = MyOtherClass(name:"Test", someotherinfo:"Bla", myclassarray: ??????????)
```

This instance of `MyOtherClass` I'm then passing from my main View to a second View via a segue.

Comment: In swift, [Array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) is copy-on-write. That means whenever you pass an array the array is copied. So you don't really need to worry about the ___new___ instance.

Comment: @nayem Not sure how the garbage collector in Swift works but it's more that I don't want to create a new `var` that I'm never going to use. I guess I'm just used to passing the new array directly. Is there then even a difference between creating a new `var` and creating and passing the array directly in Swift?

Comment: You've asked these two questions, right? 1. creating a new `var`, 2. creating and passing the array directly. And you want to know if there is any difference between them or not. If I'm correctly getting into your question, then **no, there isn't any difference**. Essentially when you pass an array to another method, a complete new instance is actually passed.

Comment: @nayem I'm new to Swift and used to just passing a new array directly in Java - without creating a direct reference first like you do in Swift with `var bla = ...`. But I've not been able to find any information on how to do the same thing with Swift yet. So yes, as a followup question it would be good to know if there's even is a point to pass a new array directly and if not, if that's the reason why I can't find anything about it.

Comment: Well, you are thinking too much about it. There are fundamental differences between **Java** and **Swift**. Java sees any object as reference but Swift doesn't always. You need to study the differences between `value` & `reference` more in Swift. Swift is designed keeping `value` types in mind. You see a lot of `struct`'s in Swift.

Comment: Now if you just want to know the answer to your question, here it is: `myFunction([myclass1, myclass2, myclass3])`. You bracket a bunch of object using `[ ]`, you create an instance of `Array`. That's it.

Comment: Yup, I am - better change stuff now than later. `You need to study the differences` - Will do. Currently I only need references though. Thanks, that's working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
myFunction(["a","b","c"])
```

This works equally well if you want to return an array from a func

```
func test() -> [String] {
    return ["a", "b"]
}
```

And it works equally well with a custom class

```
MyOtherClass(name:"Test", someotherinfo:"Bla", 
             myclassarray: [MyClass(name: "A", number: 1, content: "AAA"), 
                            MyClass(name: "B", number: 2, content: "BBB")])
```

Comment: I tried that too but it doesn't work (the type is "myclass", I just used String to make it easier to see). Instead it says: `Cannot convert value of type ‚(String, String, String)‘ to expected element type ‚String‘`.

Comment: @Neph Without seeing the actual code it is hard to help you but it looks like you are using parentheses like some tuple?

Comment: No tuples. I'm going to edit my question a bit more, hopefully it's a bit clearer then: I've got a class `MyClass` and created a bunch of instances that carry data. These instances I want to add to an array, which I'm then using to create an instance of a second class (`MyOtherClass` - including some Strings), which in turn I'm passing from my main View to a second View via a segue.

Comment: Thanks. I must have had some other brackets in there that Xcode didn't recognize as culprit, with [myclass1, myclass2, myclass3] it works.